# How to explode substr - PHP Captcha

Tags: php, captcha, explode, substr

I need your help to explode a substr function. It's for a captcha, need to have every character separate, to apply different color on each character.

Thank you.

```
$authorizedChar= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

$nbChar = rand(4, 8);

$text = substr(str_shuffle($authorizedChar), 0, $nbChar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
var_dump(str_split('testing'));
```

Would return:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 't' (length=1)
  1 => string 'e' (length=1)
  2 => string 's' (length=1)
  3 => string 't' (length=1)
  4 => string 'i' (length=1)
  5 => string 'n' (length=1)
  6 => string 'g' (length=1)
```

Comment: Thank for "str-split ()". But how can i use this to apply different color to each caracters?

Comment: @Jilu, str_split will make an array of each character, so you can loop over the array and work with one character at a time. How you create the actual captcha is not what your question is about, but take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple for-loop here

```
$authorizedChar= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$nbChar = rand(4, 8);
$text = substr(str_shuffle($authorizedChar), 0, $nbChar);
for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++)
  echo $text[$i]."<br />";
```